# Deseasonalize data - strange plot

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation, seasonality, trend

I want to deseasonalize my daily data, and I chose to verify yearly seasonality as I have prices of wheat that usually increase around the same time of the year.
I have used the function `ts` on R, using this code :

```
 Returns<-tsclean(Data$Return)
 plot(Returns)
 ts_ret<-ts(Returns,start=126,end=4223,frequency=250)
 Diff_Returns<-diff(ts_ret)
 decomp = stl(Diff_Returns, s.window="periodic")
 deseasonal_cnt <- seasadj(decomp)
 plot(decomp)
```

However, I get this plot, and I do not understand if it is normal. Note that I chose a 250 frequency since there are on average 250 trading days per year.

[image]
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You have a very long time series, hence the very compact image. Make the image bigger or look at a subset of your data.

Comment: Also the results are telling you that the most variability in your data comes from the seasonal and random component, while the trend is practically non-existant.

Comment: @user2974951: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transcribing comments into a quasi-answer.

You have a very long time series, hence the very compact image. You could plot a bigger image (in Rmarkdown with fig.width and fig.height chunk options) or look at a subset of your data to make the image less compact.

Also the results are telling you that the most variability in your data comes from the seasonal and random component, while the trend is practically non-existant